# Creating duplicate simple product will result to error in Magento 2

Tags: magento-2.1

I'm working with a site built with magento 2.1.2.

The problem is when going to admin and when I open a simple product and create a duplicate of that simple product. It will result into this error.

[image]

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Magento-2 duplicate product will not created from admin because of there is a magento-2 default version bug.

Still bug is open on github, You can check it from here : [Product Duplication crash](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/4096)

Comment: Hi S H Patel, Thanks but is this bug only in magento 2.1.2? Because Currently I'm using this version of magento 2.